# Predicting Trend using Hidden Markov Model

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-model, viterbi-algorithm

I am trying to predict exchange rates trend using Hidden Markov model (Viterbi Algorithm). For 2 state trending, I use A = [0.9  0.1; 0.1  0.9] as transition matrix and B = [1/N 1/N ....1/N; 1/N 1/N ...1/N] as confusion matrix for N symbols of observation). I expect the output would be series of up-trend state (where the sum of all exchange rate changes in this state is positive) and series of down-trend state (where the sum of all exchange rate changes in this state is negative). However, the result disappointed me since both of the up-trend and down-trend states have positive number for their sum of all exchange rate changes. This would mislead in differentiating between up-trend and down-trend. Could anyone help me and suggest what's going wrong? Does it result from wrong clustering in making N observation symbols or other problems?